# Does the matrix have full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

$M=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
4 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$

$M^{T}= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4\\ 
2 & 5\\ 
3 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$

Form this and get $\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 24\\ 
0 & 12\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow rank(M)=2$

But is this full rank now? How can you know if it's full rank? This is not square matrix that's why I'm confused, also from my previous question (about injective / surjective).

Comment: Maybe it cans help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/the-rank-of-a-linear-transformation-matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrix has *maximum* rank, which means that a matrix of its shape cannot have a rank higher than $M$. This means that the matrix is *surjective*, however it is not injective, and no matrix with more columns than rows can ever be injective.

It's easy to prove, and good practice, that

- if a matrix has more columns than rows, then it can be surjective (if it has maximum rank), but not injective.
- if a matrix has more rows than columns, then it can be injective (if it has maximum rank), but it cannot be surjective.