# How to determine the rank of the following general $\mathbb{R}$-linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

EDIT: [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/dimension-of-all-2x2-symmetric-matrices.836246/) forum post was helpful for my understanding as to why [José' Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2612303/494748) is correct. Further clarification about this general problem can be found in the comments section.

---

beginner here.

I need to calculate the rank of the following linear transformation:

$\sigma: M(2, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M(2, \mathbb{R}), A \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}(A + A^{T})$

---

Progress so far:

It seems that this question consists of two parts. (1) find a matrix that describes this mapping, (2) find the rank of that matrix, just like I would any other matrix.

(1):

$
\sigma(\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix})  \rightarrow
\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} a + a & b + c \\ c + b & d + d \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} a &  \frac{b + c}{2} \\ \frac{b + c}{2} & d \end{pmatrix}
$

At this point however I become stuck. Is my foundation correct, or do i need to approach this question differently?

P.s So far I have considered these sources:

[1) A question from math.stackexchange defining relevant terms.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/the-rank-of-a-linear-transformation-matrix)

[2) An apparently related question considering a mapping from R_2 to R_3.](https://yutsumura.com/range-null-space-rank-and-nullity-of-a-linear-transformation-from-r2-to-r3/#c_Describe_the_null_space_kernel_and_the_range_of_T_and_give_the_rank_and_the_nullity_of_T)

But I am still having trouble internalizing the methodology. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did proves that every matrix from $\operatorname{range}(\sigma)$ is a $2\times2$ symmetric matrix. Furthermore, if $M$ is such a matrix, then $\sigma(M)=M$. Therefore, $\operatorname{range}(\sigma)$ *is* the space of all $2\times2$ symmetric matrices. So, $\operatorname{rank}\sigma=3$.

Comment: Sorry to be daft, but I don't understand how you come to the conclusion that $\sigma = 3$. Would you mind elaborating that for me?

Comment: @doom01 I did *not* state that $\sigma=3$. What would that mean? What I wrote was that the rank of $\sigma$ is $3$. That's so because $\operatorname{rank}\sigma=\dim\operatorname{range}(\sigma)=3$.

Comment: sorry that was a typographical error. Thanks for the assistance, I need to think about the theory for a bit longer before I can do anything here.

Comment: @doom01 Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Accepted, as this answers my title question. So that I can learn from this, I want to try and put $dimrange(\sigma)$ into words. Would it be accurate to say it is the number of independent elements (dim) required to create each object (here 2x2 symmetrical matrices) in the range?

Comment: @doom01 $\operatorname{range}(\sigma)$ is the image of the map $\sigma$. Since $\sigma$ is a linear map, $\operatorname{range}(\sigma)$ is a vector space and therefore it has a dimension, which is denoted by $\dim\operatorname{range}(\sigma)$. Yes, it is the number of a minimal set of generators of $\operatorname{range}(\sigma)$, but I think that this is a complicated way of seing it.

Comment: I agree with you, and there are may be other ways of explaining this concept to a beginner such as myself. Nevertheless I find this explanation helpful for understanding the question. I no longer have any more questions, thanks for clarifying everything.

Comment: @doom01 I'm glad I could help.