# How can I prove that $[T]_B$ is a reversible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

given vector space $V$ so that $\dim(V)$ is finite , $B$ marked as a base to $V$, and in addition, given linear-transformation $T:V \to V$.

if $\text{rank}([T]_B)=\dim(V)$ how can I prove that $[T]_B$ is a reversible matrix?

Answer (score 0):

$\text{rank}([T]_{B})=\dim\text{Im} T$. Now $\dim\text{Im}T+\dim\ker T=\dim V$, so $\ker T=\{0\}$. Now $[T^{-1}]_{B}$ is the inverse matrix of $[T]_{B}$.

Comment: Why $dim(V)=dim(ImT)$  ?

Comment: With $\text{rank}([T]_{B})=\dim V$, so $\dim \text{Im} T=\dim V$.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Isn't that $\text{rank}([T]_{B})=\dim V$ just by the assumption?

Comment: Yes, but I don't why how you get that $dim ImT = dimV$ by it assumption?

Comment: No, that is not by assumption, do you know the formula that $\text{rank}([T]_{B})=\dim\text{Im} T$?

Comment: No, I don't know this formula

Comment: This [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/the-rank-of-a-linear-transformation-matrix) is useful.

Comment: $dim([T]_B) = dim(T)$?

Comment: $\dim T$ is not a good notation, but $\dim\text{Im} T$ is then alright.

Comment: Ok, and after you got that $ker(T)=0$ , what is the next step?

Comment: So $T$ is injective (one-to-one): For $T(x)=T(y)$, then $T(x-y)=0$, so $x-y\in\ker T=\{0\}$, so $x=y$.

Comment: Ok, but I need to prove that $[T]_B$ reversible matrix by this?

Comment: You need to show that $[T]_{B}[T^{-1}]_{B}=I$, but I guess you have known the formula that $[S]_{B}[T]_{B}=[AC]_{B}$ for mapping $S,T$. And $[T T^{-1}]_{B}=[I]_{B}=I$.

Comment: I don't understand how you know that $[T]_B$ reversible matrix by the fact that $Ker(T)={0}$?

Comment: With $\ker T=\{0\}$, $T$ is one-to-one. And in this case, since $\dim\text{Im} T=\dim V$, so $T$ is onto, and hence $T$ is bijective, so $T^{-1}$ exists. We can then talk about $[T^{-1}]_{B}$, and this is the inverse matrix by the calculation that $[T]_{B}[T^{-1}]_{B}=[I]_{B}=I$.